# Passing in a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> to WebAPI is getting me null values

Tags: javascript, c#, json, list, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass in a list of objects that contains a list of KeyValuePair objects within them, along with a few other properties, to WebAPI.  However, when I send the JSON using something like Rest Console (or even just with an AJAX call from Javascript), the list of objects populates fine, it's the List> that gets the correct number of objects, but always has null for the values.

Here's the code I have been using to debug this.

I created a WebApi method to give me a list of MyModel items, so I can see how JSON was creating them.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetSavedItemsJson(int accountId)
    {
        var tmpItem = new List<MyModel>();
        tmpItem.Add( new MyModel
        {
            ItemType = "Item1",
            MinCount = 3000,
            MaxCount = 5000,
            KeyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MinItems", "3.0"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxItems", "11.0")
            }
        });
        tmpItem.Add(new MyModel
        {
            ItemType = "Item2",
            MinCount = 1500,
            MaxCount = 2500,
            KeyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PaymentMin", "150"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PaymentMax", "500")
            }
        });
        var result = new JsonResult
        {
            MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
            Data = tmpItem
        };
        return result;
    }
```

This gives me back the following JSON:

```
[
  {
  "ItemType ":"Item1",
  "KeyValuePairs":[
     {
        "Key":"MinItems",
        "Value":"3.0"
     },
     {
        "Key":"MaxItems",
        "Value":"11.0"
     }
  ],
  "MinCount ":3000,
  "MaxCount ":5000
 },
 {
  "ItemType ":"Item2",
  "KeyValuePairs":[
     {
        "Key":"PaymentMin",
        "Value":"150"
     },
     {
        "Key":"PaymentMax",
        "Value":"500"
     }
  ],
  "MinCount ":1500,
  "MaxCount ":2500
   }
]
```

I tried adding in my additional properties and making the List of items an array.

```
{
 "itemName":"MyTestItem",
 "accountId":54321,
 "userId":12345,
 "itemModels":[
  {
     "ItemType":"Item1",
     "KeyValuePairs":[
        {
           "Key":"MinItems",
           "Value":"3.0"
        },
        {
           "Key":"MinItems",
           "Value":"11.0"
        }
     ],
     "MinCount":3000,
     "MaxCount":5000
  },
  {
     "ItemType":"Item2",
     "KeyValuePairs":[
        {
           "Key":"PaymentMin",
           "Value":"150"
        },
        {
           "Key":"PaymentMax",
           "Value":"500"
        }
     ],
     "MinCount":1500,
     "MaxCount":2500
  }
 ]
}
```

I get the accountId, ItemName and userId numbers fine.  I also get the List items with the MinCount, MaxCount and ItemType values.  It's just the KeyValuePairs list that give me 2 items for each object, but with null for the values.

The above values I used REST Console to send the values to the WebApi.

If it makes a difference, I used this javascript to create the object.  It gives me the exact same result though.

```
function saveItem() {

var saveData = new Array();
var properties = new Array();
properties.push({ "MinItems": "3.0" });
properties.push({ "MinItems": "11.0" });
saveData.push({ ItemType: "Item1", MinCount: 3000, MaxCount: 5000, KeyValuePairs: properties });
properties = new Array();
properties.push({ "PaymentMin": "50" });
properties.push({"PaymentMax": "300" });
saveData.push({ ItemType: "Item2", MinCount: 1500, MaxCount: 2500, KeyValuePairs: properties });
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Area1/SomeArea/SaveItem",
    data: { itemName: "MyTestItem", accountId: 54321, userId: 12345, budgetModels: saveData },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log("Data: " + data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

I must be doing something wrong, but am having trouble finding any decent answers on stack overflow or any other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this test here and it works! Look in my RequestTest Object.

```
public class RequestTest
{
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Test")]
[Route("api/TestInfo/Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]RequestTest requestTest)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(requestTest.ItemType);
    Debug.WriteLine(requestTest.KeyValuePairs.First().Key);
    Debug.WriteLine(requestTest.KeyValuePairs.First().Value);

    return Ok();
}



function saveItem() {
    debugger;

    var properties = new Array();
    properties.push({ "Key": "MaxItems", "Value": "3.0" });
    properties.push({ "Key": "MinItems", "Value": "11.0" });

    var requestTest = {};
    requestTest.ItemType = "ItemString";
    requestTest.KeyValuePairs = properties;

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: apiURL + '/TestInfo/Test',
        data: requestTest,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that as well with the same results.  I just left it out of my initial question as I was worried I was getting a little code heavy.

Comment: I've just tested here. Could you check?

Comment: Odd.  It's still not working for me.  Mine is a List of items with a List of KeyValuePair items in it.  So for example, requestTest in your sample above would be List<RequestTest>.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But maybe you can change your c# method and change your post object. Like ParentObject { ListProperty: List<RequestTest>  }